# Jquery select by attribute length

Tags: jquery, attributes, string-length

With jquery, is there a selector statement that directly gets all DOM objects with an atribute of a particular string-length?

For instance, in the html below only retrieve nodes with class of string-length 3 => results in divs with classes one and two ?

```
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
<div class="three"></div>
```

Comment: You can use `filter()` but i'm really not sure why you would need that... Whatever you are trying to do, sounds like a XY problem

Comment: what is an  a XY problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A slightly odd requirement, but you can use `filter()` to achieve it.

```
var $divs = $('div').filter(function() {
    return this.className.length === 3;
});
```

**-- Apr 2021 Update --**

Using ES6 this code can be made shorter still:

```
let $divs = $('div').filter((i, el) => el.className.length === 3);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a cool [function from James Padolsey](http://james.padolsey.com/snippets/regex-selector-for-jquery/) to use a regex for selecting elements.

Example:

```
// Select all DIVs with classes that are three characters long:
$('div:regex(class,^[a-zA-Z]{3}$)').css("background-color","black");
```

See full solution at:

https://jsfiddle.net/xtoakxev/

Answer (score 0):

Rory certainly has a more elegant solution, but heres something i had done, when i had a similar requirement.

```
$(function () {
      var a = [];
      $div = $('div').each( function(i , el){
          return ($(this)[0].className.length === 3) ? a.push($(this)) : null;
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is better for code reuse:

### Include jQuery

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
```

### Create custom selector `:attrlength(attr,length)`

```js
$.extend(jQuery.expr[':'], {  
  attrlength: function (el, index, selector) {
    var splitted = selector[3].split(',');
    var attrName = splitted[0].trim();
    var attrLength = parseInt(splitted[1].trim());
    var attr = jQuery(el).attr(attrName);
    if(attr) return attr.length == attrLength;
    return false;
  }
});
```

### Testing it out

#### JS

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    const elements = $(":attrlength(class,4)");
    console.log(elements[0]);
});
```

#### HTML

```html
<span class="four">Text</span>
<span class="two">Text123</span>
<span class="one">Text123</span>
```

#### Output

```
<span class="four">Text</span>
```